# Enable the order meta box

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I enable the order meta box? I want it to set the order.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'bocker', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'product_category' => 'spanskt',  'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'order' => 'ASC', ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post solved my problem: [order posts by custom field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076000/order-posts-by-custom-field)

I made a custom field instead (which suited this even better than a metabox) named "pub_year":

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'bocker', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'product_category' => 'ex-jugoslaviskt', 'meta_key' => 'pub_year', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'order' => 'DESC' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This link should have the information you need: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

There's also a tutorial on this subject here:
http://wptheming.com/2010/08/custom-metabox-for-post-type/

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, meta boxes are only created automatically for regular posts or pages, `'post_type' => 'post'`, not `'post_type' => 'bocker'`, which is a custom post type.

Comment: In the 'bocker' post type there is a meta box called Attributes, in the box it says Order and I can type in a number. Do you think I can use this meta box?

Comment: yes. without looking at code that's creating the box, it's hard to say, but type in a number, sure. you may want to change `'orderby' => 'meta_value'` in your code to `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'` so it sorts 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 instead of 1,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Comment: It ignores the order I set in the meta box. I read this in the Codex:
'meta_value' - Note that a 'meta_key=keyname' must also be present in the query. Note also that the sorting will be alphabetical which is fine for strings (i.e. words), but can be unexpected for numbers (e.g. 1, 3, 34, 4, 56, 6, etc, rather than 1, 3, 4, 6, 34, 56 as you might naturally expect).
What is the 'meta_key=keyname'?